# What is the role of self loop in Hidden Markov Models(HMM)?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, pattern-recognition, natural-language-understanding, hidden-markov-model

What actually does the self-loop (within the single hidden state ) in the Hidden Markov model helpful for?

I learn that one of the use cases concerning Natural language Understanding is that it helps a model to stay within the current state in case of (time variable: long sound/ short sound) pronunciation of the same word. But I can't understand what role the self-loop plays here.

Any explanations would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you using three-state models for phonemes?

Comment: @JaumeOliverLafont Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input audio is splitted into overlapping frames, for instance having size 40ms at a frame-rate of 20ms. For every frame $t$, some feature vector $O_t$ is observed. An input utterance with three frames would be represented as the sequence $O_1O_2O_3$.

Consider a model with no self-loops, a left-right model with three states and no skips either, with states $S=\{S_1,S_2,S_3\}$. Having no skips means that the transition from $S_1$ to $S_3$ is not allowed, it has probability $a_{13}=0$. This rigid model would be able to generate or recognize only observations of length $T=3$, and would necessarily assign the state $S_i$ to the observation $O_i$. There is no other possible alignment.

By allowing a self-transition in the central state we give temporal flexibility to the model, so different length utterances can be properly aligned and recognized. An observation of length $T=5$, for example, would be written $O_1O_2O_3O_4O_5$, and the model could generate $O_1$ at state $S_1$; $O_2$, $O_3$ and $O_4$ at $S_2$; and $O_5$ at $S_3$.

This self-transition models the number of observations in the second state (the duration $d_2$) with an exponential distribution of average $$\overline{d_2} = \frac{1}{1-a_{22}},$$ where $a_{22}$ is the probability of remaining in $S_2$. Note the extreme values $a_{22}=0$, giving expected duration $1$; and $\overline{d_2}$ growing unbounded as $a_{22}$ approaches $1$.

The symbols and formula used here come from the [tutorial by Rabiner (1989)](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ecga/behavior/rabiner1.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the proper explanations, @JaumeOliverLafont, but could you explain the scenario where a22 tends to infinity? Would the audio input having the same phonemes be one of the scenarios?

Comment: If you are modeling one phoneme with three states, a large $a_{22}$ means a long version of the phoneme, such as... in a song, for instance.
Multiple repetitions of the same phoneme can be modeled with a transition from $S_3$ to $S_1$ with $a_{31}>0$.

Comment: Got your point. Thanks!